# google maps v3 multiple infowindow out of bounds

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow, fitbounds

I got a simple map with 2 `markers` and 2 `infowindows` open.

How can i ensure the map will fit to show **entire** markers and infowindows?

This is the proof of concept.

http://jsfiddle.net/hBeX3/

Depending on the height of the screen (please move up and down the right vertical separator and run again) i could get one infowindow cutted like this:

[image]

In this example i used 2 fixed points but i want to ensure everything will be visible after a `map.fitBounds` call and with any set of `markers/infowindows`.

How can avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

```
On the basis of Screen size or Marker u can give ZOOM value.

For example

function initialize() {

var map_options = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.9169800,80.9631799),
            **zoom: 5,**
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
}
```